# Why wasn't onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) called?

Tags: android, focus

I have a button (redButton) and a modified AutoCompleteTextView (field) where when I click redButton, field will set its ArratyAdapter to redAdapter and drop down its content, but immediately when redButton loses focus, I want it to reset the adapter in onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus).  However, this method was never called when redButton loses focus.

Below is my code:

```
        redButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.d(Tag, "in red button OnFocusListener...");
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when button loses focus
                Log.d(Tag, "red button lost focus...");
                 field.setAdapter(numAdapter);
                 Log.d(Tag, "re-set numAdapter...");
                 field.invalidate();
                 field.setThreshold(1);
                 field.requestFocus();
                Log.d(Tag, "exiting onFocusChange()...");
            }
        }
    });
```

So why wasn't onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on focus for the phone means exactly that the focus(cursor) is on the field. The mouse cursor is not detected in onFocus. In fact the mouse cursor cannot be detected at all.